# validation advice for table Username and Password

Tags: php

Please take a look at this code. this is a restricted area where individuals can edit their details. at the moment I dont want individuals to edit username and password. is there any implementation to protect (validate) those fields but the details should still being displayed at the text box.

```
public function blabla($lllll)
{
    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $book = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE id =".$usr;
        $stmt = $con->prepare($book);
        $stmt->execute();
        $get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $ts = new Account;
        echo("<div id='box'>
        <div class='box-header'>". $get['']."</div>
        <div class='box-content'>
        <form method='post'>
        <table width='50%'>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type='text' size='0' name='name' value='".$get['name']."'  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Surname:</td>
            <td><input type='text' size='0' name='surname' value='".$get['surname']."'  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type='text' size='0' name='username' value='".$get['username']."'  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='text' size='0' name='password' value='".$get['password']."'  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E-mail:</td>
            <td><input type='text' size='0' name='email' value='".$get['email']."'  /></td>
        </tr>
        ");
        echo("</table></form></div></div>");
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing I can think of is XSS protection. Put ``htmlspecialchars`` around all the ``$get`` variables that are outputted.

Comment: Don't generate SQL statements by concatenating strings if you can avoid it, especially when dealing with variables that come from outside the program (anything from $_GET or $_POST for example).  Use prepared statements instead, they'll give you a level of protection against SQL injection.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="usernaame" disabled />` ?